# Is there any way to get advertising source in Firebase analytics while using Appsflyer link?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, appsflyer

I am using Appsflyer to improve my App(Android/iOS)'s marketing campaign. But at the same time, I need to use Firebase analytics to in-app analysis while Appsflyer is not a solution for in-app analytics.

The problem is get advertising(attribute) data from Firebase analytics. I need to use Onelink(from Appsflyer with Appsflyer parameters) so I cannot know from which source people came in Firebase analytics when People Installed from Onelink link. I also found it's impossible to fully integrate Firebase analytics with Appsflyer even with Google Tag Manager(I even asked to Appsflyer manager who work with my company).

Does anyone went through this kind of situation? Please help.

Comment: AppsFlyer uses Firebase for uninstall tracking only. `while AppsFlyer is not a solution for in-app analytics.` - why not? AppsFlyer supports rich list of in-app events including purchase validation. Give an example what you try to achieve with in-app events

Comment: Thanks for replying. All I want is see source/campaign etc from Firebase analytics while using Onelink. Do you think I can do that with push API?